# Pulling data from .json url causing error with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to pull data using a small script I found that seems to work with any other url that produces json data, however when I use it with a url that ends in .json, i will just receive a syntax error.

//error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : http://frontier.ffxiv.com/worldStatus/gate_status.json?callback=jQuery21309476937903091311_1450254419566&q=select+title%2Cabstract%2Curl+from+search.news+where+query%3D%22cat%22&format=json&_=1450254419567
```

//code below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Using YQL and JSONP
$.ajax({
    url: "http://frontier.ffxiv.com/worldStatus/gate_status.json",

    // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
    jsonp: "callback",

    // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
    dataType: "jsonp",

    // Tell YQL what we want and that we want JSON
    data: {
        q: "select title,abstract,url from search.news where query=\"cat\"",
        format: "json"
    },

    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is the error on console?

Comment: I've added the error into the description, sorry.

Comment: Use datatype json instead of jsonp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL you're doing the ajax request to doesn't deliver JSONP, just regular JSON.

You get a parse error because the result is something like

```
{"status":0}
```

while jQuery expects something like

```
callback({"status":0})
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like CORS is supported either, so the data from that URL can't be gotten from the clientside, due to the same-origin policy.

Comment: Sure, if you control the server on `ffxiv.com` you add the appropriate `Access` headers. If you don't control the server on `ffxiv.com` there's nothing you can do, you'd have to write a serverside script to get the data, and then use ajax to run the serverside script on your own server.